# Why is the context menu not working some of the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contextmenu

I have created a context menu item but it does not work all of the time. For instance, when I click on pause, it pauses, and when I click play, it plays again, and that happens one more time. After that, it does not do anything when I click on it. Then, it goes back to where it started. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var x = 1;
</script> 
<script>
    // JAVASCRIPT (jQuery)

    // Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {

        // Avoid the real one
        event.preventDefault();

        // Show contextmenu
        $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).

        // In the right position (the mouse)
        css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px"
        });
    });


    // If the document is clicked somewhere
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {

        // If the clicked element is not the menu
        if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

            // Hide it
            $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
        }
    });


    // If the menu element is clicked
    $(".custom-menu li").click(function(){

        // This is the triggered action name
        switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {

            // A case for each action. Your actions here
            case "first": alert("first"); break;
            case "second": alert("second"); break;
            case "third": alert("third"); break;
        }

        // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
       $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
      });
</script>
<script>
    function changeContextMenuIn() {

</script>
<style>
     /* CSS3 */
    /* The whole thing */
    .custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    }
    /* Each of the items in the list */
    .custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
    .custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
<video width="640" id="vidPlayerMain" autoplay="" controls="" onclick="if (x == 1) {document.getElementById('vidPlayerMain').pause(); document.getElementById('pauseContextMenu').innerHTML='Play'; x = 0;} else {document.getElementById('vidPlayerMain').play(); document.getElementById('pauseContextMenu').innerHTML='Pause'; x = 1;}" name="media">
    <source src="https://video-lax1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hvideo-xpa1/v/t42.1790-2/1063787_495053737243964_500266464_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjYzNSwicmxhIjo3MzZ9&rl=635&vabr=353&oh=d763b8ecfa2a823b9971c497732e4b69&oe=55C8F2C9" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<br />
<ul id='contextMenu' class='custom-menu'>
    <li data-action="first"><a href="javascript:if (x == 1) {document.getElementById('vidPlayerMain').pause(); document.getElementById('pauseContextMenu').innerHTML='Play'; x = 0;} else if (x == 0) {document.getElementById('vidPlayerMain').play(); document.getElementById('pauseContextMenu').innerHTML='Pause'; x = 1;}; $('.custom-menu').hide(100);" style="text-decoration:none; color:#333;" id="pauseContextMenu">Pause</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In web, load order matters, the jquery might not able to work when you execute `$(document).bind("contextmenu", ....`, try use `domready` or `window.onload` to wrap your logic, that ensures when you want to use jquery, its accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the function to pause and play video is bound to contextMenu's <a> element but function to alert data-action attribute is bound to contextMenu's <li> element and <a> element is not fully occupying width and height of <li> element. (The video does not play/pause at times when you click on context menu button outside of its area occupying text)

One simple solution to this is to change the CSS of these two element such that <a> element is occupying full width and height.

CSS:

```
/* CSS3 */
/* The whole thing */
.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Each of the items in the list */
.custom-menu li {    
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
}
.custom-menu li a {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```